# Python closures: function defined inside of function can access variables one level above?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, garbage-collection, decorator

I'm learning about decorators, and I have a question. In this decorator function `call_counter`, another function is defined and returned, and will "replace" the function `func` passed in as a parameter to the decorator function.

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    helper.calls = 0

    return helper
```

Once this is done, we can access `helper.calls` from outside any function in this manner:

```
@call_counter
def addition(x, y):
    return x + y

print(addition.calls)
addition(1, 2)
print(addition.calls)
```

The output:

```
0
1
```

My question is, how can the `helper.calls` variable exist in memory after the `call_counter` function has been called and exited? As far as I understand, `helper.calls` exists in `call_counter`'s memory. But this seems unlikely if the variable can be accessed after execution of `call_counter` is finished.

Comment: `calls` is related to `helper` not `call_counter`.

Comment: `.calls` is simply an attribute of each new `helper` function object returned by `call_counter`. The real closure "magic" is that the new `addition` function can call the original version of `addition` which was passed as the `func` arg to `call_counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calls` is a property of `helper` and it will live until `helper` dies, and `helper` is not going to die because, as you said, it will live under `addition` name.

Comment: How does the function `helper` die? If I wanted to "kill" `helper`, how would I do it?

Comment: The way I see it, `addition` (or `helper`) lives and dies each time I call `addition`. So shouldn't `calls` be eliminated from memory each time?

Comment: I see now that my confusion probably stems from not understanding what happens when we write `helper.calls += 1`instead of `calls += 1`. Where can I read about this?

Answer (score 0):

The `call_counter` function creates a new object (a function) every time it is called using the name `helper`. And the `call_counter` function is returning that newly created object. And as the decorator works it basically does:

```
def addition(x,y):
    return x+y
addition = call_counter(addition)
```

So now the returned object (the function previously named `helper`) is stored under `addition`.